# How to wait for one api call to complete before making another api call without using `await` in vue pinia store

Tags: javascript, callback, vuejs3

**We can use `await` but seniors suggested me that we can do this with vue's reactivity, can some one help?**

- I am working on project in group where my senior suggested that we can use vue's reactivity to handle file upload and make final `post` request, however it's confusing to me what they are suggesting, below is my implementation, can some one suggest is there any better way of doing this?

**App.vue**

```js
const isLoading = ref(0)

function Requester(url, method, data = null, callback = null) {
  // TODO: Remove primitive request counting technique and use reactive pattern
  isLoading.value++
  axios(url, { method: method, data: data })
    .then((response) => {
      if (callback) callback(response)
    })
    .catch((reason) => {
      alert(reason)
    })
    .finally(() => {
      isLoading.value--
    })
}
```

**store.js**

```js
export const documentLibraryStore = defineStore('documentLibrary', () => {
  const useDocStore = doctore()
  const useGeneratedDocStore = generatedDocStore()
  const document = useGeneratedDocStore.newDocument
  const files = ref([])

  function isUploadDoneForAllFiles(uploadCount, extraFileCount) {
    return document.files.length - uploadCount == extraFileCount
  }

  function uploadPdfs() {
    let uploadCount = 0
    let extraFileCount = 0
    document.files.forEach((doc) => {
      if (!doc.id) { // id is undefind for non uploaded file
        add(doc.fileData, (value) => {
          uploadCount++
          doc.id = value.id
          // Here I am checking if files are uploaded or not
          if (isUploadDoneForAllFiles(uploadCount, extraFileCount)) {
            publish(document)
          }
        })
      } else {
        extraFileCount++
        if (extraFileCount == document.files.length) publish(document)
      }
    })
  }

  function formatPublishPayload() {
    document.files = document.files.map((file) => {
      return {
        id: file.id,
        fileId: file.fileId
      }
    })
  }
  // This should only called once we have id's for files uploaded
  function publish(documentset) {
    formatPublishPayload()
    if (document) {
      request('URL_TO_UPLOAD_DOCUMENT', 'POST', documentset, (response) => {
        useDocStore.appendDocumentSets(response.data)
        useGeneratedDocStore.clearNewDocumentSet()
      })
    }
  }

  function add(uploadFile, setID) {
    if (uploadFile) {
      const formData = new FormData()
      formData.append('file', uploadFile)
      request('URL_TO_UPLOAD_FILE', 'POST', formData, (value) => {
        files.value.push(value.data[0])
        // this is call back I am using to set id received from backend to set for uploaded files
        setID(value.data[0]) 
      })
    }
  }

  function publishDocumentSet() {
    uploadPdfs()
  }
  return { files, add, publishDocumentSet }
})
```

Comment: why not using `await`?

Comment: Good question, I aksed the same and they suggested me we can use`vues` reactivity, which I don't understand how?

Comment: afaik vue reactivity works in any case, just needed to applied right. it's not clear though where is your problem exactly, i guess you could elaborate more

Comment: Have you tried asking "seniors" what they mean exactly or to show you an example? Your question is not clear enough to be answered.

Comment: I will ask it and see what they suggest and if there is an answer I get from them I will post it here.